# Android Google Play Games API, onActivityResult not called

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-plus-signin

**I have recently integrated the new play games api into my app, WatchStop (link below), and I am having a really hard time managing the sign out process.**

If a user signs out from the leaderboard or achievement UIs (Google's UIs), it does not sign them out locally. The GoogleApiClient will still report as connected when calling `mGoogleApi.isConnected()`. Additionally both `onConnectionFailed()` and `onActivityResult()` are not called so there is no way for me to know if they have signed out.

**I have seen some people have success with `onActivityResult()` in previous versions of the API but have not found any information about that process with the new API except this from Google:**

> Implement onActivityResult() to handle the result of the connection resolution:

`protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            // Bring up an error dialog to alert the user that sign-in
            // failed. The R.string.signin_failure should reference an error
            // string in your strings.xml file that tells the user they
            // could not be signed in, such as "Unable to sign in."
            BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,
                requestCode, resultCode, R.string.signin_failure);
        }
    }
}`

**I implemented it in this way to try and listen for a sign out:**

`@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), CLASS_NAME +
        ".onActivityResult() - RESPONSE CODE: " +
        responseCode + ", REQUEST_CODE: " + requestCode,
       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
        if (responseCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED && (requestCode == REQUEST_LEADERBOARDS || requestCode == REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS)) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            signOutLocal();
        }
    }`

The toast in the above code is never shown indicating to me that the method is never called. The Activity that I am calling this from extends `BaseGameActivity` (which I forced to extend `AppCompatActivity`). I have even tried overriding BaseGameActivity's `onActivityResult()` to statically call the one in my activity to no avail (possibly because it itself is not being called idk).

**What can I do to ensure that if a player signs out from a Google UI, they get signed out locally as well? Without fixing this if they click on either 'View Leaderboards' or 'View Achievements', they will crash because locally, the api still thinks they are connected.**

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my code above was working perfectly and I had examined the wrong build. For those interested, you simply need to look for

`responseCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED`

in

`onActivityResult()`

and you can know that you're not connected anymore so you should call your sign out methods. See the snippets above.

Comment: I had the same issue and the solution works as supposed, however not in the case, when the user goes to the leaderboards picks a leaderboard and signs out from there. When he comes back to the activity, the responseCode is 0, not RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED, and app crashes. Actually the Leaderboards/Game services crash themselves when the user tries to open another leaderboard after signing out. Tested with the latest GPGS 7.8+.

Comment: Did you submit a bug report?

Comment: No, just a crash report.